# Why can't my pre rendered blazor assembly reference a class from a shared library?

Tags: c#, shared-libraries, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I have three .net 7.0 projects.
There's a razor pages project and on one page is a blazor web assembly, as demonstrated here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly

Alongside is a shared class/model library project, shared with the blazor project, which the razor pages project can read okay.
The blazor project is referenced by the razor pages project, as it should be.
The razor page sends a parameter to the blazor assembly, 'myawesomeparameter'.
The blazor code does not run and on inspecting the browser's console, it displays the following error message:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The parameter 'myawesomeparameter' with type 'myaweomenamespace.myawesomeclass' in assembly 'myawesomelibrary' could not be found.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter 'myawesomeparameter' with type 'myaweomenamespace.myawesomeclass' in assembly 'myawesomelibrary' could not be found.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssemblyComponentParameterDeserializer.DeserializeParameters(IList`1 parametersDefinitions, IList`1 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting.WebAssemblyHostBuilder.InitializeRegisteredRootComponents(IJSUnmarshalledRuntime jsRuntime)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting.WebAssemblyHostBuilder..ctor(IJSUnmarshalledRuntime jsRuntime, JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting.WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(String[] args)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I have tried adding the models to the blazor project, but then the razor pages can't see them!!!

Comment: I should like to add, the intellisense, when working in the blazor code, can read the class type, perfectly well and the solution builds okay.

Comment: What exactly is this shared library? Like blazor component library, or a "backend" class library (ex. model, data, service layer)

Comment: It's just a project of shared models, @Narish.

Comment: @sanepeter and the DLL for this model layer is directly referenced by *both* the blazor and razor solutions right? I think the issue could be that the model layer is referenced by one and not the other and you are attempting to use that missing reference

Comment: In both MVC and MVVM models a lot of times that model/DTO layer is going to get referenced by every other project in the solution as they will need those objects to do their work

Comment: Just to clarify, I have added the 'model' project as a project reference to the 'web assembly' project and both the 'model' and the 'web assembly' projects as project references to the 'razor pages' project, which issues the same error message as just referencing the 'model' project as a project reference to the 'web assembly' project and just the 'web assembly' project as project reference to the 'razor pages' project.

Comment: The issue seems only to be with accepting a model class as a parameter in the web assembly pre rendered by the razor page.

<component type="typeof(MyAwesomeComponent)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" param-MyAwesomeClass="@(Model.MyAwesomeClass)" />

Comment: I have a similar situation, client WASM project, server project, shared project. I try to set an instance of sharedProject.object in the server _host.cshtml.cs and pass it to the WASM component, and get a similar message. But passing simple types like strings works.

Comment: I also get a warning: The type 'MyClass' in '\shared\MyClass.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'MyClass' in 'wasmClientApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in '\shared\MyClass.cs'.

Comment: I think that with the server app referencing the client app which also references the shared project, the compiler gets confused. But to do <component type="typeof(client.App)" you need to reference the client from the server.

Comment: Haha!
I haven't touched this technology since, had to do it again and hit the same problem.
I was so happy to find the exact problem on SO, then realised I'd already asked and answered it.
Today's a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray!
Prompted by the responses to this question, I tried using a dynamic component, but it wasn't what I wanted.

I tried adding extra @using references for the model class, to no avail.

Lastly, I tried sending a simpler parameter from the razor page to the blazor assembly and it worked!

I couldn't send a complex object, but a serialised string, which is then deserialised in the blazor web assembly, fixed everything.
It's not what I'd prefer, but it works.